# How to code a RNN model using LSTM from deeplearning4j (DL4J) for regression to predict speed of a vehicle?

Tags: java, regression, lstm, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I'm new to DL4J and I need to code a RNN with LSTM to predict the future value of the speed of a moving vehicle. I have only one input which is the the time index and one output which is the speed.

I've been researching for a while now on this, but it's really complex and I don't know how to code the actual model; how many hidden layers, which layers, number of nodes, activation, weight, etc.

I tried the example of the CSVModel for regression from the DL4J itself, and tried to modify the layers to LSTM but unfortunately it's not working as the data needs to be in 3D arrays and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a better fit for our community forums: https://community.konduit.ai/ the stack overflow forums are typically for "I have this code how can I fix it" not for general instruction.